# POS Screen not opening in Ofbiz

Tags: point-of-sale, ofbiz

I'm a newbie to Ofbiz. I've successfully built Ofbiz 13.07.01 by running `ant.bat load-demo`. But the command `java -jar ofbiz.jar pos` doesn't open POS screen; it just shows the Ofbiz logo & that's it. Tried in JDK8(Win 8.1 & 7) & JDK7(Win7). What could be the issue? Please help.

Please note: I'm able to open webstore, catalog.

---

### Edit

After building, `pos` directory is absent inside `specialpurpose`. Also, there is no entry of `pos` in `component-load.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Ofbiz 13.07.01 doesnot come with POS or any other components except ecommerce. Downgraded to 12.04.05.

Thanks to userML, especially Taher, Jacques, Hoan & Pierre.